# Prevent C# Speech Synthesizer repeating itself on button click event

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that uses the C# Speech Synthesizer.

which i want to cancel when the applicaiton opens and read inputed text, tried below

```
base.onclosing
```

but not working?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx, I see methods for 'pause' and similar there. Please confirm you tried these and looked at the code doco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doco: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx

EXACTLY THIS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj572477(v=office.14).aspx#Anchor_4

Something like the following should work, your just creating a variable that can be accessed so its a single instance of speechsynthesizer

```
private SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
private void SpeechButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Cancel the current speak operation and all queued SpeakAsync operations.
    synth.SpeakAsyncCancelAll();

    // Begin speaking the prompt.
    synth.SpeakAsync("Hello, Welcome to the application");
}
```

See that second link for more example code, basically just use a variable to track the same instance and a Cancel type method (several examples in first and second link) to stop current running speeches.

Comment: @Nitesh - see my edit, it does what it says, just play with timing and exact methods to find your desired flow.